# Proving Ideal in $\mathbb{C}[x, y ,z]$ is Prime

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am working on a problem, and my proof would be complete if I could show that $I = (2 + x + z, y - xz - x^2)$ is a prime ideal in $\mathbb{C}[x, y ,z]$. The methods I know (e.g., showing that $\mathbb{C}[x, y ,z] / I$ is a domain) don't seem to work well here; how can I show that $I$ is a prime ideal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:* Prove the map $\mathbb{C}[x, y ,z] \to \mathbb{C}[x]$ given by $p(x,y,z) \mapsto p(x,x(-2 - x) +x^2,-2 - x)$ is a surjective ring homomorphism with kernel $I$.

Comment: I'm confused about how you defined your map - the image doesn't seem to be a point in $\mathbb{C}[x]$?

Comment: His map $p$ sends triples to elements of $\Bbb C[x]$ all right: substitute $x$ for $x$, $-2x-x^2$ for $y$, and $-2-x$ for $z$.

Answer (score 1):

We can simplify the quotient ring to $C[x,y]/J$ where $J=(xy-x^2+3y)$ by eliminating $z$. It is easy to see that $xy-x^2+3y$ is irreducible and so the ring is a domain.